# Creating model instances from raw sql

Tags: sql, django, count

Is there any way to create model instances from raw sql in django? I have a problem with additional count queries done by [django.paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/core/paginator/) (it's veeeeery slow), which I want to replace with one query that takes filtered data with count by using raw sql with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

The main point is, I need the data to be returned as model instances, because I don't want to rebuild all my templates.

Comment: Please share either an example of what you want or what you have attempted in order to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Django supports [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) queries which can be mapped to models if you need more control than that offered by the ORM.

```
for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM app_person'):
    print(p)
```

If you're just trying to add a count to queries, will [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) not suffice?

```
p = Person.objects.annotate(children_count=Count('children'))
```